# Compare two sets of XY Coordinates and align them

Tags: c#, geometry, 2d, computational-geometry

I have two sets of X,Y co-ordinates as separate lists. Both represent the same irregular polygonal shape, but in different orientations and sizes/scale.

Need to write a program in C#, to compare both the points set, rotate any one of the shape such that it aligns with the another, so that they are in same orientation.

Tried searching for solution, and got to know using concave hull with angles difference can help, but could not find a good C# implementation for the same.

Can some one help me, if there is a minimal way to achieve this?

**Edit: The two points-set might not be the same. One may contain more points than other.**

**I have contour co-ordinates of a shape and a PNG which is of same shape, but orientation is different. I want to read the PNG, calculate the angle to turn it to the fit the Contour.**

[image: Sample of a PNG]

Comment: You can start by calculating the distance to the points in both lists and comparing those. Should be able to see if one is a factor of the other. If you know the factor you can scale one up or down to see if they are equal.

Comment: The mainthing you want to do is calculate each of the angles.  The sequence of angles will be the same in a pair of "same irregular polygonal shape(s), but in different orientations and sizes/scale".  Get the list of angles the same, and you will know which corners in one polygon line up with which corners in the other.  That said, without showing some code in your question, you likely won't get any answers.

Comment: Thanks @fstam, but my major requirement here is to rotate one shape with respect to another, so that they both match and orient. Basically i hope i have to find the angular difference between them from the points-set and rotate one to that angle, so that it align with the other. Any idea for that?

Comment: Just thinking loud. Try to sort each collection in respect to the center, you could find center, then take the first two points of both, as one side of the polygon, and calculate angle between. After that rotate one polygon around the center.

Comment: Show examples. We cannot reply blindly.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate [image moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment) for point cloud

Evaluate orientation of both clouds with `Theta` angle.

Rotate one cloud by theta difference.

Use other moments (centroid etc) to find translation and scale

Comment: The Hu moments are rotation invariant, by design. The covariance matrix can be used, but in the case of symmetric clouds, it fails. Orientation from moments is an uneasy problem.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Yes, just central moments. About symmetry -  author  mentioned `irregular `(while we have not seen examples yet)

Comment: Irregular is not incompatible with symmetric. But above that, an asymmetric polygon can have symmetric moments. Orientation from moments is an uneasy problem.

Comment: @Yves Daoust  The same doubts exist for min/max diameter of convex hull using rot. calipers.  Moments calculation might be prerequisite for Iterative Closest Point algorithm (perhaps overkill there)

Comment: Yes, orientation of a point cloud is an uneasy problem. In the bad cases it can be wrong by any angle.

Comment: @MBo, thanks for your suggestion, i managed to get the Orientation Theta for both the shapes mentioned before, using moments. However, the HuMoments values differ to a major extent even though the shapes are similar. Also, i am getting the theta values (in degrees) for two images as 1.36 and -16.77 (negative) respectively. Can you guide me how to interpret them.